# Still Booting to Windows after Debian Install

Tags: linux, debian, grub, bootloader, mbr

I recently installed Debian Linux to one of of my storage drives alongside Windows 7 (on a different drive) and for some reason when I start up my computer I still boot right into Windows instead of GRUB. I assume this is because it was not installed to my MBR correctly for some reason. Are there anyways to fix this so it does boot to grub or am I going to have to reinstall Debian to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you have install debian on another physical drive GRUB have probably been install on this drive, but your motherboard is probably set to boot on the hdd containing windows.

You can boot on a live cd and install grub on the hdd containing windows 7. After, if your windows 7 installation is not recognized you'll be able to edit your grub configuration and add a windows entry.

Here is the debian grub installation [tutorial](http://wiki.debian.org/Grub)

The other solution is to set your motherboard to boot on the hdd where Debian is install. Like the first solution, if Windows 7 is not recognized, you juste have to add an entry to the grub configuration.

Comment: The Live CD option sounds good. What are some good ones?

Comment: Debian live http://live.debian.net/ is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you had to install it on another drive? So you could try going into the BIOS and changing the boot priorities from there. Since it sees the windows drive first, it boots of that one.

NOTE:
This will only work if you installed it on another hard drive and not just a partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a "live-cd" from many linux distributions. I usually use [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) as it boots on lots of hardware. Burn that to a cd (usualy a "write image" option). That will "unpack" the .iso file onto the disk. When finished, boot the cd (you may have to set your BIOS to boot to the cd drive first).